# AJAX postback in jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm having an AJAX request on the page.

Is there a way to find when a AJAX-call is triggered on the page.
In jQuery or javascript to find or initiate a function with AJAX request is called on a page.

Answer (score 2):

See [`ajaxStart`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxStart) and [ajax events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). Example:

```
 $("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $(this).show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

Comment: @santhosh - can show what you've tried in the question? It's hard to picture what you're trying to do based on information you have given.

Comment: $(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", function() {
    Sys.Debug.trace(this);
});


for this its working,  but its bind all ajax rquest. How can i filter to find particular ajax call.

Comment: @santhosh - just use $.ajax's beforeSend, complete and success callbacks then :)

Comment: There only problem comes, i can't add anything $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to a JQuery object to be completed when any AJAX call completes.

```
$('#status').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    // Do stuff here...
});
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback).

If you want to set a complete function for a single AJAX call, use the low-level `$.ajax()` function and setting a function for the `complete` attribute.

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    complete: function(request, settings) {
         // Do stuff here...
    },
    // ...
});
```

Note: the documentation seems to contradict itself in specifying the number of arguments to the `complete()` function. It may take some fiddling.